# How to replace partially asp.net page with a jquery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

Let's say, I have a Listview control on the page. Each Listview item has 2 dropdownlists and 1 textbox. When the first dropdownlist has a selected value changed, the second dropdownlist should be populated with city depending on the first one. Finaly, when a value is selected for the second dropdownlist, a cost should appear on the textbox.

```
<asp:ListView ID="_lsvCostFinder" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
            <tr  runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlCountry" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlCity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="_txtCost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Now I want to use ajax when user selects a different value for the dropdownlist

```
$('select').change(function () {
   $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged",
  data: "{}",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
    //
  }
 });
```

I want to replace only the entire **tr** element. Those are my questions:

1. What should I send in the data? The value of the dropdownlist?
2. How do I replace only the **row** containing the dropdownlist that triggered the ajax call?

## EDIT

All the methods have the following signature

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It's a very long and complex page.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Good choice; ASP.NET partial postbacks are horrible. My life became much simpler when I stopped bothering with them. I just implement everything as a webservice now and return JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, looking at the sample code you posted and how you plan to make the Ajax call, you  will need to enable `PageMethods` in your page. [See this tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) on how to do that part.

The actual ajax call using jQuery can be as simple as this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
     $.post('Default.aspx/MethodName',{selectedVal:$(this).val()}, function(data){
         //as far as placing the result in the input text field, I think this will do:
         $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text').val(data);
     });
});
```

Now, your `MethodName` method would have to look like this:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string MethodName(string selectedVal)
  {
     return "something";
  }
```

[jsfiddle (minus the ajax call).](http://jsfiddle.net/ESKtF/)

## Update

Sorry, I misread the question, the OP wants to replace the WHOLE row. This will do then:

```
 $(this).parents('tr').replaceWith('<tr><td colspan="3"><div>'+data+'</div></td></tr>');
```

Full context:

```
$('select').change(function () {
         $.post('Default.aspx/MethodName',{selectedVal:$(this).val()}, function(data){
             //as far as replacing the row, this will do:
               $(this).parents('tr').replaceWith('<tr><td colspan="3"><div>'+$(this).val()+'</div></td></tr>');
         });
    });
```

Comment: look at the edit. As I said up there, those methods exist already. Is there any other way of doing this without changing method signature?

Comment: @Richard77 No, it's not possible to do it without changing the method signatures. There's no concept of `object sender, EventArgs e` in an Ajax call. It all comes down to key,value pairs from the HttpRequest.